# Mapcache не кэшит WMS с mapserver

Tags: nginx

Настроил mapserver(WMS источник), mapcache c nginx на ubuntu. По инструкции:

```
  http://mapserver.org/id/mapcache/install.html#cgi-fastcgi-specific-instructions
```

Nginx *.conf:

```
location ~ ^/maps/ofp_10000(?<path_info>/.*|$) {
    set $url_prefix "/maps/ofp_10000";
    mapcache /mapcache/ofp.xml;
    error_page 404 = @fastcgi_mapcache;
}

location @fastcgi_mapcache {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
    fastcgi_index mapserv;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING   map=/ofp_10000/vrt_all.map&$query_string;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE   $content_type;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME    $server_name;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT    $server_port;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO      $path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME    "/maps/ofp_10000";
 }
```

ofp.xml:

```
 <mapcache>
     <cache name="tmp1" type="disk" layout="template">
            <template>/tmp/mapcache/{tileset}#{grid}#{dim}/{z}/{x}/{y}.{ext}     </template>
    </cache>

     <source name="vmap0" type="wms">
           <getmap>
            <params>
               <FORMAT>image/jpeg</FORMAT>
               <LAYERS>vrt_all</LAYERS>
           </params>
         </getmap>

       <http>
         <url>http://host/maps/ofp_10000?</url>
       </http>
   </source>

  <tileset name="vrt_all">
        <source>vmap0</source>
        <cache>tmp1</cache>
        <grid>WGS84</grid>
        <grid>g</grid>
        <format>JPEG</format>
        <metatile>2 2</metatile>
        <metabuffer>10</metabuffer>
        <expires>10000</expires>
        <auto_expire>86400</auto_expire>
   </tileset>

   <default_format>JPEG</default_format>

   <service type="wms" enabled="true">
        <full_wms>assemble</full_wms>
         <resample_mode>bilinear</resample_mode>
       <format>JPEG</format>
       <maxsize>4096</maxsize>
  </service>
  <service type="wmts" enabled="true"/>
  <service type="tms" enabled="true"/>
  <service type="kml" enabled="true"/>
  <service type="gmaps" enabled="true"/>
  <service type="ve" enabled="true"/>
  <service type="mapguide" enabled="true"/>
  <service type="demo" enabled="true"/>

  <errors>report</errors>
  <log_level>warn</log_level>
  <lock_retry>10000</lock_retry>
  <lock_dir>/tmp</lock_dir>
   <auto_reload>false</auto_reload>

 </mapcache>
```

WMS работает везде, показывает демо-мапкэш:

```
http://host/maps/ofp_10000/demo/wms
```

но никакого кэша в /tmp/mapcache нету, папка пустая, может что упустил, не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working, bad instruction, needed start mapcache.fcgi and configured in nginx, like:

```
    location ~ ^/mapserver/ofp_10000(?<path_info>/.*|$) {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
            fastcgi_index mapserv;
            fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING   map=/ofp_10000/vrt_all.map&$query_string;
            fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
            fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE   $content_type;
            fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
            fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME    $server_name;
            fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT    $server_port;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO      $path_info;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME    "/maps/ofp_10000";
    }

    location ~ ^/maps/ofp_10000(?<path_info>/.*|$) {
            set $url_prefix "/maps/ofp_10000";
            mapcache /usr/local/share/mapcache/ofp.xml;
            error_page 404 = @fastcgi_mapcache;
    }

    location @fastcgi_mapcache {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9002;
            fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
            fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
            fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE   $content_type;
            fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO      $path_info;
    }
```

and mapcache init.d:

```
              #! /bin/sh
               if [ "$NETWORKING" = "no" ]
                then
                       exit 0
               fi
               PREFIX=/usr
               NAME=mapcache
                PID=/var/run/mapcache.pid
                DAEMON=$PREFIX/bin/spawn-fcgi
                DAEMON_OPTS=" -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9002 -F 4 -u www-data -U www-data -P $PID $PREFIX/local/bin/mapcache.fcgi"
                MAPCACHE_CONFIG_FILE=/usr/local/share/mapcache/ofp.xml
             start () {
                        export MAPCACHE_CONFIG_FILE=$MAPCACHE_CONFIG_FILE
                         echo -n $"Starting $NAME "
                         exec $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS >> /dev/null
                         daemon --pidfile $PID
                        RETVAL=$?
                          echo
                       [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ]
             }
             stop () {
                     echo -n $"Stopping $NAME "
                     killproc -p $PID
                      #make sure all mapservers are closed
                    pkill -f mapcache.fcgi
                    RETVAL=$?
                     echo
                    if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] ; then
                          rm -f $PID
                    fi
            }
            restart () {
               stop
               start
            }

            if [ -f /lib/lsb/init-functions ]; then
              . /lib/lsb/init-functions
            elif [ -f /etc/init.d/functions ]; then
              . /etc/init.d/functions
            fi
            # See how we were called.
           case "$1" in
               start)
                    start
                   ;;
               stop)
                     stop
                     ;;
               status)
                    status lt-mapserv
                    RETVAL=$?
                  ;;
               restart)
                  restart
                 ;;
              *)
                    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
                      RETVAL=2
                       ;;
            esac
           exit $RETVAL
```

and ofp.xml change url:

```
              <source name="vmap0" type="wms">
               <getmap>
                  <params>
                     <FORMAT>image/png</FORMAT>
                      <LAYERS>vrt_all</LAYERS>
                     <MAP>/ofp_10000/vrt_all.map</MAP>
                  </params>
                </getmap>

                 <http>
                      <url>http://host/mapserver/ofp_10000?</url>
                 </http>
              </source>
```